# Observable collection not updating treeview using silverlight child window

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a problem with my silverlight treeview which is bound to an observable collection. The treeview binding is working perfectly across all operations apart from when I try to edit an existing item in the treeview, in which I popup a new child window and pass the treemanager object to it. Treemanager is essentially a custom class maintaining my observable collection. The code updates the underlying item in the observable collection as if it seems to have a pointer to the treemanager object, but it doesnt update the treeview, even if i specifically tell it to rebind to the obervable collection.

Code for right click:

```
TreeViewItem treeItem = this.RCM.GetClickedElement<TreeViewItem>();// as TreeViewItem;

TreeManager treeManager = ((TreeManager)(((HeaderedItemsControl)(treeItem)).Header));

if (treeManager.Type != "diObject")
{
    Message.ErrorMessage("Please select the root DiObject to edit");
    return;
}

EditWindow editdlg = new EditWindow(DiObjectNameToList(treeManager), driverComboItems, deviceIntTypeComboItems);
editdlg.Title = "Edit DIObject - "+treeManager.Title;
editdlg.Closed += new EventHandler(editdlg_Closed);
editdlg.t_orig = treeManager;
editdlg.t = treeManager;
editdlg.Show();
```

Child view window:

```
public partial class EditWindow : ChildWindow
{
    Dictionary<string, string> diObject;
    String[] driverComboItems;
    String[] deviceIntTypeComboItems;

    public TreeManager t { get; set; }
    public TreeManager t_orig { get; set; }

    public EditWindow(Dictionary<string, string> _diObject, String[] _driverComboItems, String[] _deviceIntTypeComboItems)
    {..}
}
```

treeManager class:

```
public class TreeManager
{
    public TreeManager() { }

    public TreeManager(string title)
    {
        Title = title;            
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeManager> childElementsValue = new ObservableCollection<TreeManager>();

    public ObservableCollection<TreeManager> ChildElements
    {
        get { return childElementsValue; }
        set { childElementsValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeManager class does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. So changes in the Title do not get propagated to the bindings and user interface.

Comment: you don't need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged. The problem is that he is setting the list directly, and Observablecollection doesn't not notify if it is set directly, only when you do .Add() ; Clear() ect...

Answer (score 0):

Observable collection implements the INotifyCollectionChanged, and that is raised only for :

> /// Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or
>   the entire list is  public virtual event
>   NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

when you are assigning directly you are creating a complete new list, thus no notification.

Comment: The reason he is not being notified is because he didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the TreeManager! Which should raise the PropertyChanged event when the ChildElements property changes. For instance when he replaces the the collection.

Comment: Not really, he is not getting notified, because he is assigning a whole new Collection to his new collection. Good practice is to encapsulate the collection, and provide Clear() , Add() , Remove(), those methods will automatically raise the PropertyChanged that the ObservableCollection raises. If you have reflector or ILSpy, check the implementation of the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Basically we shouldn't do this :    set { childElementsValue = value; }
This doesn't raise the events since it's a new collection. However what you suggested as a solution works, but it's just not using the ObservableCollection mechanism, he can basically use normal List in this case.

Comment: I agree that it is not elegant or efficient but it is possible.